# How to increase the scale of a shape based on more than 1 CGPoints?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I'm adding a new feature for a drawing app library and I'm implementing a pinch to resize feature for it. For example I have a Line shape created by connecting 2 `CGPoint`s. I want to increase the size of the shape by using `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` since it has the `scale` property. So far what I've done is this:

```
// The startPoint is the point of the first finger of the gesture, and the endPoint is the second finger.
// The scale value is from the UIPinchGestureRecognizer class
func handlePinch(startPoint: CGPoint, endPoint: CGPoint, scale: CGFloat) {
  ...

  var castedShape = SomeShapeWithTwoPoints...
  let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
  castedShape.a = castedShape.a.applying(transform)
  castedShape.b = castedShape.b.applying(transform)

  ...
}
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't behave as I expect it to (I would say the calculated points are too big and it positioned the points outside of the view). Since I'm not sure where did  I do wrong, My question is how do I get the updated `CGPoint`s based on the scale value of the pinch gesture the correct way?

**EDIT:**

For example, I have the first line before the gesture was done. It has 2 points A and B. When I do the gesture, I want the line to be longer while keeping the position like this. In order to achieve this, I want to calculate the A and B points based on the scale of the pinch gesture (I just need the new points after the gesture was done). Is there any way to do this?

[image: Line diagram]

Comment: You've asked a very vague question... Are you trying to draw a line from the first finger point to the second? Or have you defined a line path from p1 to p2, and you want to scale that line?

Comment: @DonMag I've added a picture for you to see. I hope it should be clearer what I want to achieve.

Comment: OK - are you using a `CAShapeLayer` to display the line? Or overriding `draw()` in a `UIView` subclass? Or do you simply want to change the x,y values of ptA and ptB?

Comment: @DonMag Since the drawing logic is already handled by the original author of the library, I just need the updated x and y values of both points. I could set the points for the shape object and the shape will update itself automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're running into when scaling with a `CGAffineTransform` is that the transform is relative to `0,0`.

So, if you have points at:

[image]

a `2.0` scaling will result in:

[image]

Which is, obviously, not what you're going for -- you want the distance between the points to grow (or shrink) based on the scale factor.

There are several ways to do this...

Let's use some math.

We'll start with two points:

[image]

As we know, any two points can be used to define a line segment:

[image]

Thanks to Pythagoras, we can easily get the length of the line -- **and** easily find the center-point on that line:

[image]

Now, what else can we do with a line and its center-point? We can define a circle:

[image]

and the circle's radius:

[image]

Now, if we want to "scale the points by 2.0", we can scale the radius to define a new circle:

[image]

and, with just a little more math, we can get the angle of the line and then "find the point on the circle":

[image]

and we've moved the two points away from each other, by the scale factor, keeping them on the original line.

Here's a quick example...

We'll start with some "convenience" `CGPoint` funcs:

```
extension CGPoint {
    
    static func pointOnCircle(center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, angle: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        let x = center.x + radius * cos(angle)
        let y = center.y + radius * sin(angle)
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }
    
    func angleToPoint(otherPoint: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        let originX = otherPoint.x - self.x
        let originY = otherPoint.y - self.y
        return atan2(originY, originX)
    }
    
    func distanceToPoint(otherPoint: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        return sqrt(pow((otherPoint.x - x), 2) + pow((otherPoint.y - y), 2))
    }
    
    func centerBetween(otherPoint: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        let xDiff: CGFloat = otherPoint.x - x
        let yDiff: CGFloat = otherPoint.y - y
        return .init(x: x + xDiff * 0.5, y: y + yDiff * 0.5)
    }
    
    func scaleOnLineTo(otherPoint: CGPoint, scale: CGFloat) -> (CGPoint, CGPoint) {
        let p1: CGPoint = self
        let p2: CGPoint = otherPoint
        // get center point between p1,p2
        let center: CGPoint = p1.centerBetween(otherPoint: p2)
        // get radius (distance between center,p1)
        let radius: CGFloat = center.distanceToPoint(otherPoint: p1)
        // angle (radians) from center to p1
        let a1: CGFloat = center.angleToPoint(otherPoint: p1)
        // angle (radians) from center to p2
        let a2: CGFloat = center.angleToPoint(otherPoint: p2)
        // new p1 is point on circle with radius * scale
        let scaledP1: CGPoint = CGPoint.pointOnCircle(center: center, radius: radius * scale, angle: a1)
        // new p2 is point on circle with radius * scale
        let scaledP2: CGPoint = CGPoint.pointOnCircle(center: center, radius: radius * scale, angle: a2)
        return (scaledP1, scaledP2)
    }
    
}
```

a simple "round" view:

```
class PointView: UIView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.width * 0.5
    }
}
```

and a demonstration:

```
class PinchExampleVC: UIViewController {
    
    let vP1 = PointView()
    let vP2 = PointView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        
        vP1.backgroundColor = .red
        vP2.backgroundColor = .blue
        
        vP1.frame.size = .init(width: 20.0, height: 20.0)
        vP2.frame.size = vP1.frame.size
        
        view.addSubview(vP1)
        view.addSubview(vP2)
        
        let pg = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePinch(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(pg)
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        vP1.center = .init(x: view.bounds.midX + 40.0, y: view.bounds.midY - 80.0)
        vP2.center = .init(x: view.bounds.midX - 40.0, y: view.bounds.midY + 60.0)
        
    }
    
    @objc func handlePinch(_ gestureRecognizer : UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        
        if gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {
            let (xp1, xp2) = vP1.center.scaleOnLineTo(otherPoint: vP2.center, scale: gestureRecognizer.scale)
            vP1.center = xp1
            vP2.center = xp2
            gestureRecognizer.scale = 1.0
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

As I said, there are several ways to do this. Depending on what ***else*** you might need to do -- for example, if you need to scale multiple points, a bezier path, etc -- you'd need to investigate transforms a bit more.

But, for your specific question, this should do the job.